# Haar Cascade Training for Parts of a Known Object

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, object-detection, haar-classifier, object-recognition

I am working on a project where I am trying to extract key features of a bicycle from an overall image. I am currently investigating the use of Haar Cascades to train my computer to find certain regions of interest from said bicycles, e.g. the pedal-sprocket, seat, handle-bars. Then I will extract local features from these sub regions accordingly. The purpose is to create an overall descriptor of a particular bicycle so I can try to match it throughout a sample set of images of other bicycles.

My questions are as follows: Can I train a Haar classifier to look for a sub-component of an overall object? For example, say I want to look for the handlebars on a bicycle. How should I design the training? Should I detect the bicycle first, and *then* detect the handlebars within the overall bicycle region (Similar to detecting the eyes within a face in terms of facial recognition)? Since I know beforehand that all my images will contain a picture of a bicycle, I'm not sure if there is any point in detecting the bicycle to begin with and then looking for sub components.

In terms of training a Haar cascade and creating an XML that I can use (in OpenCV 3.1 and Python 3.6), could I just set up the positive and negative images with pictures of bicycles and no bicycles respectively? With the difference being that I isolate the particular area of interest by cropping the image appropriately each time (e.g. where the handlebars are)?

Also open to any recommendations about how others might solve the general problem of extracting key features for object matching. This is just one approach I am currently investigating. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you want to do object detection as well as localization. you can train Haar classifier but you can get better results using deep learning based models.
Have a look here https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/object_localization_and_detection.html

Comment: That is very useful, thanks! Since writing this I am investigating deep learning models, specifically the YOLO object detection algorithm. I have got it working for the PASCAL VOC Data set, however the next challenge is to train it to classify and detect the different bicycle sub-components as a means of focusing in on them for further analysis. Basically, I want to custom train it to look for bicycle wheels, pedals etc. DO you think that is possible?

Comment: Yes, you can train your own object detection like YOLO, Tensorflow object detection API, here is a GitHub repo https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset also look in the blog. 
Here's awesome tutorial series on the same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U&t=13s

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip @Aquib Javed Khan. I have just finished setting up the Tensorflow object detection API and it is working well. The tutorials are really straight forward and I am now in the process of training some new models!